# Querying values that may be nil in Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

In my app I have a tableview which loads comments from users. In parse, I have a "Comments" class. In this class there is a column for an image (called "images"  and a column for the comment in words (called "theComment").

In order to submit a comment, the user must type something in the text box (all comments must have words). However, not all comments must have an image associated with them (the user can opt to not post an image). Here is my current code to retrieve the comments:

```
       var query6 = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
       query6.whereKey("to_post", equalTo: post!)
       query6.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (caption: [AnyObject]?, erreur: NSError?) -> Void in
              if erreur == nil {
               // on a réussi

             for caption in caption! {
                              self.newArray.append(caption["theComment"] as! String)
                                self.commentPhotoArray.append(caption["images"] as! PFFile)

  }
      self.tableView.reloadData()

     }
  else {
       // on n'a pas réussi
     }

})
```

The problem though is that this line:

```
   self.commentPhotoArray.append(caption["images"] as! PFFile)
```

says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value", because not all comments saved have associated images. is there any way around this? I tried setting it so that if the user does not manually upload a photo, it saves a dummy image that I imported to my image Assets instead, and that could work, as long as when I am unwrapping the image data (in cellforRowatIndexPath) it recognizes the dummy image and appropriately sets the height of the image view constraint to 0 (in other words, not showing the image), leaving just the comment to show. Any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check if there is an image available before you unwrap it. I can't test this code easily so if you could see if there is an error that would be great.

```
   if caption["images"] != nil { 
self.commentPhotoArray.append(caption["images"] as! PFFIle)
}
```

Comment: Sometimes != nil does not work and you have to use a different testing method to see if there is a image in the caption["images"].

Comment: What part didn't work did it give an error before you compiled it or after when you loaded the app on a simulator or device?

Comment: if `caption["images"]` returns an array, you should use `caption["images"]?.isEmpty == false`

Comment: sorry i should have been specific. it didn't work meaning it returned "fatal error-accidentely found nil while unwrapping an optional value." It did that before the view loaded (I call the method that does this in the viewDidLoad).

Santhosh I will try that now.

Comment: @Santhosh I just tried that and still received the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value" message. The error occurred at the line of    if caption["images"]!.isEmpty == false {         It did not occur at the line self.commentPhotoArray.append(caption["images"] as! PFFIle).

Comment: @joey You are getting the error since you have unwrapped the optional by using `caption["images"]!.isEmpty`. Replace this with `caption["images"]?.isEmpty`.

Comment: There are many ways to check, All you're doing here is trying to see if there is anything in the array, so you can display it.

Comment: @Santhosh I tried that first, but Xcode autocorrected it to caption["images"]!.isEmpty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var query6 = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
        query6!.whereKey("to_post", equalTo: post!)
        query6!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.") // This will print how many objects are in your Class.

                if (objects!.count > 0) {

                for caption in objects! {
                          self.newArray.append(caption["theComment"] as! String)
                            self.commentPhotoArray.append(caption["images"] as! PFFile)

                   }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }
```

I also have to say, I'm pretty impressed that someone's coding in French... Idk if that was you or someone else, but pretty cool ;)